Can't Enable Pub/Sub Topic For My Project
I have a project created and when I try to enable events (aka a Pub/Sub topic) I just get an error "Could not update project data". I've tried multiple projects and have the same issue.

This has been reported to Google as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/348675996
